# US citizen denied entry to the UK; will it go away if I renew my passport or get an enhanced drivers license?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, passport-stamps, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry to the UK due to unpaid [house sitting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_sitting) (though I was originally let in for 45 days the first time after telling them I was house sitting).

There’s a big ol’ X in my passport now and it’s going to raise lots of questions wherever I go and make house sitting in other countries difficult. I want to house sit in Canada and am thinking of getting an Enhanced Driver’s License or just renewing my passport, which I need to do soon anyhow.

My question is: Besides the UK, what countries will know about my denied entry if there’s no paper proof in front of them? How will this haunt me besides making entry to the UK difficult? How will the US government approach this when I renew?

Comment: Under the Five Eyes intelligence alliance, your information will be shared electronically between the United States, Canada, the UK, Australia, and New Zealand. Posted as a comment (not an Answer) as I have no information about your 2d and 3d questions.

Comment: Some countries (such as the US and UK) consider house sitting as employment which isn't permitted for visitors to do. Others don't care. I'm afraid I don't know offhand which Canada is, but I can say you should always answer the border guard's questions truthfully.

Comment: Can you provide a link for the Five Eyes info on denied entrants? I can't find any info that Five Eyes share info on folks not on watch lists. Where can I find info that says that anyone refused entry is blacklisted? I know CA and US have an info sharing agreement. I don't see anything that states for other non-criminal info that they share. I'd love to read up on that. Thanks!

Comment: You’re certainly not blacklisted

Comment: Nobody said it was a blacklist. It's just information sharing. You should expect any of those five countries to ask you about whether you've ever been refused entry, and you will have to explain the situation. This is not a guaranteed refusal of entry anywhere, not even back to the UK. And renewing your passport will not help.

Comment: I was paranoid enough to just call the CA border guards. I asked about the house sitting, and the officer, paused, sounded amused and said, you don't need a visa, but if you want you can call Immigration, and gave me the number for the CA consulate. The woman who answered also paused, sounded amused, and said, that's not an issue. I mentioned the UK detention and denial for house sitting and she said, that's...unusual. It's a non-issue in CA. But it might help to have a note from the person I'm house sitting for stating what I'll be doing and for how long to hand to border officers.

Comment: Under the five eyes, your fingerprints will be compared and information will be shared only if they match. Apart from USA-CANADA, other countries only share fingerprints for asylum cases. The UK immigration officers must have retained your fingerprints. However, as a US citizen you are not required to submit fingerprints to visit any FCC country. They won’t know you were refused entry unless they ask or they ask for fingerprints.

Comment: @greatone "your fingerprints will be compared": what fingerprints? Are visitors to the UK now fingerprinted?  They were not the last time I visited a few years ago.  "information will be shared only if they match": matching name, date, and place of birth isn't sufficient to link two passports to the same person?

Comment: @phoog he would have been fingerprinted when he was denied entry. 2) information between FCC is only shared if there is a biometric match. They send fingerprints anonymously. If there is a match they share names, dob, etc. There is a way to share biographic information but there needs to be reasonable grounds of suspicion. In either case, sharing is usually limited to asylum cases.

Comment: @greatone but returning to the UK, he would not be fingerprinted unless the passport scan turns up a red flag.  And it probably will, because the UK will match the biographic data.  Or was your comment intended to assert that the US wouldn't know about the refused entry?  That seems reasonably likely.  Anyway, even if they did, it should not affect the passport renewal.

Answer (score 6):

What happened to you with your current passport happened to you and will stay with you also with a new passport.

But as you should renew your passport soon, it does not hurt to do it a bit early. You will then no longer have the big X in your passport. But when asked about whether you have been denied, you have to answer yes. If you answer no and they find out you will be in bigger trouble like a long time ban and the need to apply for visa in more countries.

The UK will be able to connect you to both your new and old passports.

As you have noticed other countries may ignore the denial, but do mention it when asked about it.

Comment: Most other countries won’t care about the big X.